# Hide Markers - Mapbox

Tags: javascript, dictionary, mapbox, box

I have added markers as given in example below.

```js
for (let x = 0; x < mapMarkers.length; x++) {
  //mapObject.totalMarkers.push(createMarker(mapMarkers[x].whereLat, mapMarkers[x].whereLng, mapMarkers[x].id, detailContId));
  markerClusters.addLayer(createMarker(mapMarkers[x].whereLat, mapMarkers[x].whereLng, mapMarkers[x].id, detailContId));

}

markerClusters.on('clusterclick', function(a) {
  zoomLevel = mapObject.getZoom();
  if (zoomLevel < appConfig.userSetting.maxZoom) {
    mapObject.zoomIn();
  } else {
    a.layer.spiderfy();
  }
});

mapObject.addLayer(markerClusters);
```

Now I want to hide some markers. I have done some Rnd like given below but not able to succeed. Any help is great for me.

```
objMap.removeLayer(mapMarkers[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
objMap.removeLayer(mapMarkers[0]);
```

This would make sense if you were adding mapMarkers to the map, but as this code shows, that isn't the case: mapMarkers is the data that you transform into marker objects using the `createMarker` method before adding to the map.

Conceptually, you have `mapObject`, that contains `markerClusters`, that contains markers (which you aren't assigning variable names to). So, if you want to remove a specific marker from the markerclusters, you need to call `removeLayer` from the cluster's perspective, not from the map's.

So you can use `markerCluster.eachLayer`, like

```
markerClusters.eachLayer(function (layer, i) {
  if (i == 0) markerClusters.removeLayer(layer);
});
```

That would remove the first layer. If you have some other criteria for *which* cluster you want to remove, you'll need to either store the markers in an array before adding them to the cluster, or change that simple `if` statement into something that tests whether the marker should be removed.